# Error on row collection

Tags: c#

I'm beginner and please bear with me. I have an error:

> "Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative
>   and less than the size of the collection."

What I wanted to achieve is to click a row on my datagridview and pass all value of selected row on a textboxes.

Here is my code below:

1st I'm selecting everything on "table" and use MySqlDataAdapter to fill my DataTable.

```
    private void loadrecord()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection loadcon = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
            loadcon.Open();
            MySqlCommand loadcom = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table1", loadcon);
            MySqlDataAdapter loadad = new MySqlDataAdapter(loadcom);
            DataTable loaddt = new DataTable();
            loadad.Fill(loaddt);

            BindingSource loadbindsource = new BindingSource();
            loadbindsource.DataSource = loaddt;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = loadbindsource;
            loadcon.Close();
        }
    }
```

2nd I'm calling the function loadrecord on Form1_Load

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     loadrecord();
    }
```

Finally, I have this dataGridView1

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
     //I have 3 records. 1 Balice Book1, 2 Coyman Book2, 3 Pale Book3
     //Click primarykey on datagridview "1" and pass the value of selected   row of "1", pass "1" to Textbox1, pass "Balice" to Textbox2 and pass "Book1" to Textbox3
     //What I have tried so far is this:
     Textbox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
     Textbox2.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
     Textbox3.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
     //then this error appear whenever I try to click the cells
     //Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
    }
```

Thank you so much if you did reply on this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
Textbox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

to:

```
Textbox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
```

Also have a squiz at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs(v=vs.110).aspx .

Comment: Sir I will try it out and see if I still get the error. thank you so much

Comment: Actually it is working however when I set the cell[0] the column_name is passing the value on textbox instead of column_id. just a quick question sir. I know its not possible to use -1. Is it possible to get the column_id? I really wanted to get the row value of column_id. I only have 4 columns on my datagridview

Comment: That sounds like a different issue? If so, you may wish to create a new post with your new question.

Comment: Is it? I have 3 columns now "Column_ID", "Column_Name" and "Column_Value". It should be set to 0, 1, 2 right? but when I use 0 for cell like Cell[0] whenever I click a cell on a Column_ID it doesn't pass any value "1" but when I click the cell on Column_Name it passes a value of Column_ID "1" to a textbox . what I wanted is to pass the value "1" of Column_ID to textbox whenever I click a cell from Column_ID. Sir mjwills you are truly helping me its my first time to ask question here and you are very helpful thank you so much and sorry for bothering

Comment: I also noticed that after like 7 or 5 clicks on other cell on column_name sometimes the value on column_id is not being passed to textbox instead the textbox has the same column_id value of my last clicked column.